# If a constructor can't return null, why do I need to type-check after initialization?

Tags: kotlin, null, option-type

So given:

```
val c: Circle? = Circle(5)
println(c.circumference())
```

Kotlin compiler complains that `circumference()` can't be called because `c` could be null. Is that true? Or is the compiler a dirty no good liar?

Comment: I’d say the compiler is not smart enough to spot this; it should perform a smart cast. OTOH, this is a contrived example, an IRL it may be so much more difficult to spot that it’s not worth the trouble.

Comment: I suspect you are correct as well, but wanted to validate that opinion a bit. You are correct in other comments that this is not real code - I am actually presenting Kotlin to my team at work, and was explaining how smart casts allow calls on nullable types. This lead to me considering this case, trying it out, and being surprised by the result. I was wondering if there wasn't some edge case that made this necessary, but can't think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is a dirty no good liar. There is no way that `c` could be `null`. Since `c` is a `val`, there is no (legal) way for it to change its value, for instance in another thread, and it is provable that `c` cannot be `null`. Consider the slighty simpler case (no external classes required):

```
val i1: Int? = 42
val i2: Int = i1
```

Even this will not compile. However, the following will:

```
val i1: Int? = 42
checkNotNull(i1)
val i2: Int = i1
```

Here, the `checkNotNull` (from `PreConditions` in the standard library) performs some null check, and the compiler will create a smart cast. I assume JetBrains could fix the compiler, but there would be little use outside of demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[kotlin official compiler](https://play.kotlinlang.org) complains about unsafe calls on nullable type

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Circle?

Nullable is unneeded and can be removed in your case

```
val c: Circle = Circle(5)
println(c.circumference())
```

Comment: That’s true, but not an answer to the question. I’m sure the OP trimmed down his code a lot. Well, actually it’s not even 100% true, since the compiler uses smart casts in other places.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel but if it's `val` and assign with constructor then it doesn't need add nullable `?`. if it's complicated maybe OP should create a new non nullable object using `c`

Answer (score 0):

Because you explicitly set the type to `Circle?` you also set code semantics to expect null values.

Comment: The compiles uses smart casts in other places. A type being optional does not necessarily mean that you cannot invoke methods on it. You can call `if (c != null) println(c.circumference())`.